# Como convertir Imagen a string en Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Buenas Amigos.

Estoy intentando convertir un elemento de tipo Xmarin.Forms.Image a un string para guardarlo en base de datos local. E intentado usar el que utilizan convirtiendo una imagen a string usando la parte de base 64, pero a diferencia de C#, el tipo Image es diferente. 
Me gustaria me ayudasen.

Saludos desde Honduras a toda la comunidad.

Comment: cuando dices "base de datos local", te refieres a Sqlite?

Comment: Si, en una base de datos de SQLite.

Comment: En ese caso, lo normal es [usar un blob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357943/579895)

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, desconozco el uso de un blob, me podria decir como hacer en ese caso, si la recibo como Image, y tengo que guardarla como blob, de ser necesaria una conversion. Saludos

Comment: Joel, si pinchas en mi comentario anterior te dirige a una pregunta de [so] donde se explica como hacerlo

Comment: De todas maneras, yo creo que sería mas sencillo y eficiente guardar las imágenes en el sistema de archivos y en la base de datos almacenar simplemente la ruta...

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
byte[] ImageData = File.ReadAllBytes(RutaFoto);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
```

Comment: se te agradece el aporte pero no es solo responder pegando código y ya, debes explicarlo, dale editar después de leer [answer] y añade un contexto